# css transition on a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, transition

I have a simple component that transitions in/out depending on the prop it receives from its parent. However, i would also like this component to animate on mount as well as whatever prop it receives. I can get one or other to work, but not both.

So what to achieve is:

1. Label component mounts => animate the label in AND out
2. Receive `showLabel` prop from from parent, if true => animate in, if false => animate out

The code below satisfies #2, but not one.

```
const label = ({ showLabel }) => {
 return (
    <div style={{
        opacity: showLabel ? 1 : 0,
        transition: 'opacity 1s ease-in-out',
    }}
      <p>my label</p>
    </div>
 );
}
```

Comment: I don't quite fully understand your question. Could you add some example use cases? If you want it to show the label during mount then shouldn't the label just be shown by default and only hidden from the prop?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you will get better solution if you add use cases and little more code like what other stuff you tried, it helps us understand what exactly you are upto.
Else you will receive solution based on speculations & assumptions.

I am assuming you are using hooks because that is what it is now.
I just used useEffect that is similar to componentDid* functions based on params it receives.

```
const Label = ({ showLabel, setShow }) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setShow(true);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        opacity: showLabel ? 1 : 0,
        transition: "opacity 1s ease-in-out"
      }}
    >
      <p>my label</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Label showLabel={show} setShow={setShow} />
      <button onClick={() => (show ? setShow(false) : setShow(true))}>
        Click Me!
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. in your code, how does setShow affect the transition? it still seems that the transition would only occur when showLabel is true or false.
The part i am struggling with is for the label component to animate in then out on mount, then again when a button is clicked, like you have it

Comment: When the component  mount setShow will make your showLable=true. So the label transition happens. then now onwards transition happen on button click.
Did you try running it? Or Did I understand the requirement wrong.